# Php keeps giving me an incorrect response for android in-app-billing server verification

Tags: php, android

For some reason I got this script to work without fault but once i tried to decode the JSON the script started messing up. I reverted back to the old script and it still isn't working. Here it is below. $result keeps giving me 0 which if the PHP documentation is correct means that the verification failed. I have double checked public_key.pem to see if it is correct and it is. I have also checked to see if signedData and signature are being sent and they are being sent. What could possibly be wrong with this script?

```
<?php
$signed_data = $_POST['signedData'];
$signature = $_POST['signature'];
$fp = fopen("./public_key.pem", "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 451);
fclose($fp);
$pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);
$signed_data = trim($signed_data);
$signature = base64_decode($signature);

$result = openssl_verify($signed_data, $signature, $pubkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
if ($result == 1) {
    echo 'correct';
} else if ($result == 0) {
    echo 'fail';
    echo '||';
    echo $pubkeyid;
    echo '||';
    echo $signed_data;
} else {
    echo 'epic fail';
}
openssl_free_key($pubkeyid);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: signedData in /home/stackits/public_html/verify_script.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: signature in /home/stackits/public_html/verify_script.php on line 4
fail||Resource id #3||

Is the report I get back. I haven't changed those variables though when they worked.

Comment: If `$_POST` has undefined indices, the script was incorrectly posted to. `var_dump($_POST)` to see what, if anything, is in there. The error is possibly from the client sending the POST rather than in the PHP code...

Comment: var_dump($_POST); gives me array(0) { } I have also double checked my client posting and it is correct as well, meaning $signature and $signedData both contain data and it is in the proper format.

Comment: But clearly `$_POST` is empty so PHP received no post data.  Your client might be incorrectly sending via `$_GET`, for example. `var_dump($_REQUEST)`.

Comment: Opps, my bad I ran the script using browser of course there wouldn't be anything in var_dump. When I ran it through client I got array(2) signedData and then signature

Comment: If the $_POST values are what you expect them to be then I can't help anymore. Given you had `Undefined index` notices earlier, I am still skeptical the post vals are populated as you think they are.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with openssl it seems which was reported here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60936 which looks like it could be the same issue you're having.

Comment: Thank you! Finally i can have some relief after 18 hours of researching to know that this isn't my fault. However, I don't understand what I can do to fix this? Is it how i'm generating my .pem file?

Comment: Possibly the only thing you can do is generate a new certificate. From what I can tell from that bug report it only happens every now and then. I'm guessing you generated a new cert when you re-did the code the second time?

Comment: actually the certificate can not be changed as it is a public key assigned to me by Google Developer Panel. So basically i'm screwed because of bad luck?

Comment: It may not even be the issue I posted which is the cause. The person here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/al3sPjH4HQI was having the exact same issue as you with the exact same code. Turned out their pem file had newlines at the end of it

Comment: Nope, I've followed all of those advices and it didnt help.